# Rails, refer to an association by a custom, unique field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a Person object with the `uuid` column. Each person has_many blogs, each blog belongs_to a person.

I would like for `blog.person_id` to return the `Person.UUID`, and blog.person to return the person object.
Is there a way to do this **without making Person's primary key its own UUID**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mention the column name with `primary_key` option.

```
has_many blogs, primary_key: "uuid"
```

[has_many options](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Options) :

> **:primary_key**
>
> Specify the name of the column to use as the primary key for the association. By default this is `id`.

Comment: So, there is no way to make this happen without the Person's primary key being its own UUID? I only asked because I know of this method, but I'd MUCH rather leave the Person id as ID and change blog to reference the UUID exclusively.

Comment: @JapanRob You misunderstood. You are setting `primary_key` just for this association, your main primary key is still `id`. Only when you call `person.blogs`, and `blog.person`, the join will happen between `person.uuid` and `blogs.id`

Comment: To make the reverse association work, I also had to specify the primary_key: UUID on the belongs_to side. Thank you very, very much. Answer upvoted and accepted!

Comment: @JapanRob Ah I see. I missed that to include. Glad that you figured that out.